# Ruby: How to find XML child element from specific element using xpath?

Tags: ruby, rexml

Given xml

```
<a>
    <b key=1>
        <c value=xxx />
    </b>
    <b key=2>
        <c value=yyy />
    </b>
</a>
```

**Goal**: Get each "b" first, then get the "c" under that "b", like result below. With XPath for searching child.

```
for <b key=1>
    <c value=xxx />
for <b key=2>
    <c value=xxx />
```

but below code

```
b_elements = XPath.match(xml, "//b[@key]")
b_elements.each do |b_element|
    puts b_element.elements["//c"]
end
```

will result in yeilding

```
for <b key=1>
    <c value=xxx />
    <c value=yyy />
for <b key=2>
    <c value=xxx />
    <c value=yyy />
```

instead of just getting the "c" under each "b"

I had tried below method but no luck, seems that **if using Xpath, it will automatically search from root element**

```
b.get_elements("//c")
XPath.first(b, "//c")
```

My workaround now is traverse child element 1 layer at a time and search for desired key, which seems quite stupid comparing to using XPath. 
Please advise, thanks : )

Reference:
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/REXML/Element.html#method-i-each_element_with_attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure here, but my assumption is that XPath looks at the **first char**, sees that it is a `/`, and thinks that the path is absolute (because the path starting with `/` is meant to be absolute).

Probably you can force the path to be relative by using a `.` before `//`, so the parser doesn't confuse `//` for `/`?

I mean, instead of `"//c"` use `".//c"`? Hope this helps.